# A pair vs a couple

Tags: grammar, difference

The two women whispered to each other, acting like a pair/couple of giggly teenage girls.

Are "a pair" and "a couple" used interchangeably in a sentence like this?

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, they are interchangeable. For me "couple of giggly girls" flows a little better (the dactylic rhythm is better)

In other contexts they are not the same, compare:

> Those two are a right pair!
>
> Haven't you heard, they're a couple now.